# Odoo : Generate HTML file inside tmp folder

Tags: python, odoo

How to generate and store HTML file inside tmp folder When print the report in Print menu in ODOO11C ?

Comment: Do you need the report HTML after parsing the report template?

Comment: Yes, When I am printing PDF report or HTML report then I want to store report in HTML format in tmp folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the web main [controller](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py#L1550)

```
report = request.env['ir.actions.report']._get_report_from_name(reportname)
context = dict(request.env.context)
html = report.with_context(context).render_qweb_html(docids, data=data)[0]
```